# How to minimize the screen space occupied by Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

The deafult windows file explorer (explorer.exe) is wasting my screen space with its menus and sidebar. Usually, what I use it for is copying files from one directory to another. I could do that from cmd.exe or powershell but typing out the path in that case is kind of taxing. I need more space on my screen dedicated to the actual content and less to navigation GUI. I hope what I'm asking is clear.

I'm more comfortable with keyboard shortcuts and the space that windows UI takes is just frustrating for me.

I'm interested in tiling windows better on my screen. The space on-screen is like real estate (precious, as Sal Khan says), it's not worth wasting. Would love to hear your input.

Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers.  This close vote was issued specifically because of the statement, "Please suggest an alt explorer for windows.", there is no way to do that without a software recommendation.  As for doing the following,"Please suggest an alt explorer for windows.", I don't choose to do that.  I suggest looking at the help center to better understand the scope here at Superuser.

Comment: @Ramhound The question has been edited. Please review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply looking through the View tab in Windows Explorer shows me you can remove the Navigation pane, this in addition to the standard toolbar collapse supported in nearly every MS application.

**Hide the Navigation pane**

1. Open the **View** tab
2. On the left side, click **Navigation pane** and uncheck **Navigation pane**

The navigation pane on the left should now be gone.

**Hide the Ribbon**

1. In the upper-right corner, right next to the help icon, click the arrow-up icon.

Your ribbon is now hidden.

Comment: Thanks. Are there any shortcuts for doing this? If not, how do I set this as the default way explorer.exe should look like. Also, is there any way to get a little bit more space?

Comment: The UI is hard coded. It moves only the ways designed. These are the ways the Explorer UI is designed to move. The only way to get more movement is to use a theme, and these are notable in their lack of a replacement for Explorer. I'm not aware of any keyboard shortcuts to activate these views, however once set they should remain as the normal view until changed.

Answer (score 2):

To collapse the "Ribbon bar" click on the menu, or right click and Minimise Ribbon.

You could download an XP or 95 theme for the most minimalistic. Unless of course you want Windows 3.1 with its dos like Explorer.

Or just navigate within a command prompt with Tabbing acting like auto complete.

Comment: Assuming I don't have a mouse, what do I do?

Comment: Use a keyboard? A touch screen? What do you mean?